# What's the proper way to prove P$\rightarrow$Q is not tautologically equivalent to Q$\rightarrow$P

Tags: propositional-calculus

I want to rigorously show that [$(p \rightarrow q)\equiv(q \rightarrow q)$] is not true.

$Let A =(p \rightarrow q), B =(q \rightarrow q)$

I tried to prove this by supposing $A$ and showing that $B$ does not follow.

[$(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow (q \rightarrow p)$]

I expanded that but it didn't $= 0$

I was told to look at Reductio Ad Absurdum, but I don't see how that applies in this case.

This is a real-world example.  This is not homework.

Comment: Show a value assignment for $P$ and $Q$ where the two formulas have different truth values.

Comment: Also, please expand on how this can be a "real-world example".

Comment: Please, fix either the title or the question.

Comment: @egreg It's possible to show that A above is not equivalent to B above by a similarly method used to show that (P -> Q) is not equivalent to (Q -> P).  Namely, you assume the second thing and then show that the first thing can evaluate to falsity.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Sure, but the title and the question don't agree anyhow.

Comment: @egreg, Sorry.  Thought I had fixed it.  Fixed now.

Comment: @Bluebaron: It still says $Q\to P$ in the title but $q\to q$ in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to construct the truth tables and see that they are not equal. Or you could show values of $P$ and $Q$ that make them different (which would amount to mention the specific line of the truth tables where they differ).

If $P$ is true and $Q$ is false, then $P\to Q$ is false, while $Q\to P$ is true.

Edit: Changed $Q\to Q$ to $Q\to P$, to go with the title.

Comment: Nope.  I screwed up that comment, too.  I meant for $P \rightarrow Q$.

Answer (score -1):

Assume $B$.  Show that $A$ could be false.

By a similar method you can show that if B holds true, then (p $\rightarrow$ r) could be false.